# Path aliases to paths in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to make URL aliases in an angular 6 application. The problem is the following:
I have a URL in my angular app defined as `article/:id`, that maps to a component called `ArticleViewComponent`, but, the thing is I'm trying to make a different url where I can send the title of the article as the path for the article. For example, if I have an article called `Article about angular` with id `1`, I want the URL to be `/article/article-about-angular`and still map it to the article with id `1` (because the id is what the API handles, not the title). Thanks in advance for your help, I know this seems impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have them both map to the same component using `article/:id` as you are already using. Instead of just being a *numeric* id, this will now contain either an article title **or** a numeric id. Then when fetching the article, simply handle it differently based on whether the id is a number or a string:

```
// Check if id is "not a number"
if(isNaN(id)) {
    // Define a function to convert from titles to id numbers
    var idNumber = getIdNumberFromTitle(id);
    getArticleFromTitleName(idNumber);
} else {
    getArticleFromIdNumber(id);
}
```

Comment: What can I do if the API can't handle the title? I mean, I receive a json with all the articles, they have the title, id, and machine name (which is the `article-about-angular` string) but, when I want to get the article, I can only get it through the id, not through the title

Comment: If you have a json list of *all* of the articles, then you could create a function that returns the id number if you give it a title. Then that id could be used to fetch the article.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I don't have only one list of articles. Those are grouped by the "network" they belong to, and they are in different NGXS states (I didn't mentioned this because I didn't though it was needed, sorry). Though we're now working on a service that gives me the id and type of the content. I'll let you know as soon as we get it, thank you :)